# Making TreeView Nodes Not Expanded by Default

Tags: asp.net, treeview

Good day Guys,

I have a Treeview i used as Navigation. By default when the page loads, the Nodes with subnodes are expanded. 
I want this subnodes to be hidden by default and should only expand when clicked.

Below is the code for my TreeView presently:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TV_Navigation" runat="server" ImageSet="Simple" NodeIndent="10" 
    DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
  <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#DD5555" />
  <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px"
    NodeSpacing="2px" VerticalPadding="0px"></NodeStyle>
  <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
  <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px"
    ForeColor="#DD5555" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set the `ExpandDepth` property of the control to 0. -1 is the default which shows all nodes.

[See here for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.expanddepth?view=netframework-4.8)

> Gets or sets the number of levels that are expanded when a TreeView
>   control is displayed for the first time.